# how create object from query with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Platform and PlatformCategory is connected as belongs_to has_many

I have such query to my DB

```
    p = PlatformCategory.where(params[:platform_category_ids]).includes(:platforms)
```

I want to use each id of Platform associated to p variable and put it into new object, like this:

```
    p.each { |plat_cat| Campaign.create(..., some_id: plat_cat.platform.id) }
```

but PlatformCategory has_many Platforms and here I want to call each with block on plat.cat, but It's sounds like not Ruby way.

**UPD**
everything is ok when I pass just array like [1,2,3,4], but with array in params I get *'NoMethodError: undefined method `joins' for Array'*

Comment: Will you please let me know what exactly I missed in my answer that didn't resolve your issue so I can update/remove it accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?:

```
p = PlatformCategory.where(id: [1,2,3,4]).joins(:platforms).select('platforms.id)
```

and then:

```
p.each { |plat_cat| Campaign.create(..., some_id: plat_cat.id) }
```

**UPDATE**: Since `find` will not chain the `joins` method as it will return an Array(if you pass an array as argument) after the query. You can do this to avoid such scenario:

```
p = PlatformCategory.joins(:platforms).select('platforms.id').find([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Yes, your right @User089247 your answer makes it but, when I change to this  p = PlatformCategory.find(params[:platform_category_ids]).joins(:platforms).select('platforms.id') it gives me 'undefined method `joins' for #<Array:0x007fcf3d40b488>'

Comment: Well, you didn't mention `find` in your question. I wonder why people don't give details upfront in their questions(nothing personal with you, I am saying in general), you would be like 15th person who's asked something else in the question but then demand something else in the comments. Again, please don't take it personally, it's something which we should consider that people can not help unless you provide exact details of your situation. Please see the updated answer.